# MySQL connection on Node js with different servers

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database-connection

I'm new on node js. For security purposes, I have separated my node js and mysql in different servers and I'm trying establishing the connection like that:

```
connMySql = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "IP_PUBLIC_SERVER",
    user: "user",
    password: "secret",
    database: "myDB",
    port: 3307
});
```

Return `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED PUBLIC_IP:3307`

My question is: Is it possible to establish a remote connection using IP on host property?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Is it possible?  Yes. If it didn’t work, what error did you receive?

Comment: @AdamAzad, yes in first place.

Comment: @ParrettApps => Error: connect ECONNREFUSED PUBLIC_IP:3307

Comment: Try to use telnet to connect to your MySQL.  If it is listening on 3307, `telnet <PUBLIC_IP> 3307` should return something other than "connection refused" message.  Also, MySQL typically runs on port 3306, so try that if you can't connect on 3307.

Comment: @ParrettApps, with telnet i have getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND. I tried with port 3306 too and nothing

Comment: That's strange.  ENOTFOUND is usually a DNS issue, but if you're using IP address, DNS isn't used. Can you paste the exact code, including the actual IP you are trying to reach?  Don't paste username or password though.

Comment: @ParrettApps I already post the in below post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this openning a SSH connection and then connect mysql using locahost as a host.

Comment: Your public IP of 35.34.126.82 does not appear to be accessible on port 3307 or 3306.  You may be faced with a firewall issue.  But if your MySQL is running on a separate server than node.js, you shouldn't reference host the way you have it. It isn't on localhost from your node.js server. The host line should be `host: '35.34.126.82'` and the port should only reference the port MySQL is configured to listen on.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49830885/edit) the question and put this there.